# Problem with downloadable products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, downloadable

I was notified by one of my customer that he was unable to download the file that he bought recently. Whenever he clicks the link, website gives this error message-"***An error occurred while getting the requested content. Please contact the store owner***."

I tried checking this and found that he's true! I'm not able to figure out the exact reason for this. I believe the ',' and '/' at the end of download link are responsible for this error. This is link address of the downloadable file that I'm getting in front end, as a buyer.

https://www.mywebsite.com/downloadable/download/link/id/MC44NTA5MzIwMCAxNDI4ODg5NTUyMTkxNDI5Nw,,/

PS: I'm not a technical guy so any sort of detailed help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That is the generic error for "I tried to fetch it but I failed and I don't know why"

You have to check the settings for the downloadable product, verify the file is there, and it has permissions to read it as a start.

The commas at the end of it is part of the hash-code (hide the file name), and the / ends and separates the value from any more url input